# How to update foreign key referenced table using trigger, in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Say I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE person 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    phone INT,
);

CREATE TABLE volunteers 
(
    person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    skill VARCHAR,
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Could I create a trigger on `volunteers` that could insert into `person` table when I insert a new record in `volunteers` table.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO volunteers (person_id, name, skill) 
VALUES (12345, 'abc xyz', 'cooking');
```

If not using trigger, is there any alternatives?

Comment: You want to create a trigger on person or volunteer. You question is not properly phrased.

Comment: The `Volunteers` table does not have a `name` column. That insert statement would fail.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but you can do the following:

- Create a view with all the columns you want, joining the tables.
- Write an `instead of` trigger to update the view

The use of such triggers on views is defined in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx).

The view would look like:

```
create view v_volunteers as 
    select v.person_id, p.name, v.skill
    from volunteers v join
         people p
         on p.person_id = v.person_id;
```